# How to integrate the course package (xAPI) exported from Articulate in a customized LMS and track the course completion status, etc?

Tags: lms, xapi, rise, articulate

I'm very new to xAPI and would like to have some advice on integrating a course package exported from Articulate(https://articulate.com/) using xAPI.

The following steps are carried out or tested and it's okay to view the course

> 1. Create a course in Articulate and exported it as an xAPI-compliant package
> 2. Unzip the package and upload it to the server of a customized LMS (written in Laravel)
> 3. Include the index.html from the xAPI package and embed it in an iframe

My question is how I can get the completion status of the course (embedded in an iframe) using xAPI.

Also, how can I pass the completion status (if saved in the db of the customized LMS) to the course so that a learner re-visits the course and view the last saved progress?

Are there any good JS or PHP libraries to achieve this and the steps?

Thanks for your answer in advance!